# Unable to add BigDecimal value in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

```
def total = new BigDecimal("0.00");
total.add(new BigDecimal("1"));
println total;
```

Consider the following code above: The output of this code is zero.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to assign the result (see the docs below). or get groovy:

```
def total = 0.0G + 1G
assert total.getClass() == BigDecimal
assert total==1.0G

total += 1.0G
assert total.getClass() == BigDecimal
assert total==2.0G
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#add%28java.math.BigDecimal%29

> ```
>  public BigDecimal add(BigDecimal augend)
> ```
>
> Returns a BigDecimal whose value is (`this` + `augend`), and whose scale is max(`this`.scale(), `augend`.scale()).
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> `augend` - value to be added to `this` BigDecimal.
>
> #### Returns:
>
> `this` + `augend`